# Barcelona airport terminal 2B to Liceu by public transport

Tags: public-transport, budget, spain, barcelona, bcn

What's the easiest way to get from Barcelona Airport (Terminal 2B) to the Liceu area (or nearby, don't mind walking from another stop) using public transport (not taxi).

Arriving day time, so no issues with late services not running etc...

Originally assumed I could purchase a T10 ticket, but apparently this doesn't cover the Terminal 2 metro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are in Terminal 2B it is handy to take the train to go to the city center.

The train stop is 10 minutes walking from the terminal. You just have to walk through a long-elevated corridor (it crosses a big road).

You can find the timetables in [Rodalies Renfe's](http://www.renfe.com/EN/viajeros/cercanias/barcelona/) webpage. Select *Aeroport* as Departure Point and *Barcelona-Passeig de Gràcia* as Destination. For this you can use your [T-10 ticket](https://www.tmb.cat/en/barcelona/fares-metro-bus/travel-cards/t-10) to pay for the trip, contrary to the metro that needs an extra payment.

The train works every 30 minutes and the trip is just 26 minutes. When you arrive, you are 5 minutes far from the central Plaça de Catalunya and 15 minutes walk from Liceu, through the Ramblas. So it is a nice, turistical walk to your destination.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to take the local 46 bus and drop off at Plaça Espanya, then either take the Metro L3 to Liceu or walk the distance from Plaça Espanya (a bit long, but perfectly doable).